# time measurement total time vs cpu time

Tags: c, performance, time

I wrote a sample program to understand the time measurement in C.Below is a small self contained example.I have a function do_primes() that calculates prime numbers.In the main() function between timing code I call do_primes() and also sleep for 20 milliseconds.I am measure time using struct timeval (which I understand returns clock time.) and also cpu_time using CLOCKS_PER_SEC.Now as I understand it,this denotes the time for which the CPU was working.

The output of the program is as follows.

```
Calculated 9592 primes.
elapsed time 2.866976 sec. 
cpu time used 2.840000 secs.
```

As you can see the differnece between the elapsed time and cpu time is

```
 0.026976 seconds OR 26.976 milliseconds.


1) Are my assumptions correct? 
2) 6.976 milliseconds is accounted for my the scheduler switch delay?


#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_PRIME 100000

void do_primes()
{
    unsigned long i, num, primes = 0;
    for (num = 1; num <= MAX_PRIME; ++num)
    {
        for (i = 2; (i <= num) && (num % i != 0); ++i);
        if (i == num)
            ++primes;
    }
    printf("Calculated %ld primes.\n", primes);
}
int main()
{
    struct timeval t1, t2;
    double elapsedTime;
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;
    int primes = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;

    start = clock();

    /* start timer*/
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

    /*do something */
    usleep(20000);

    do_primes();

    /* stop timer*/
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    end = clock();

    /*compute and print the elapsed time in millisec*/
    elapsedTime  =  (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      /* sec to ms*/
    elapsedTime +=  (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;    /* us to ms */

    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("elapsed time %f sec. \ncpu time used %f secs.\n",(elapsedTime/1000),cpu_time_used);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

The additional 6.976ms might not mean anything at all, because it's possible that the `clock()` function only has a resolution of 10ms.